# Mythical Creatures associated with Bells

Tags: mythical-creatures

Pretty much what it says on the can. I was wondering if there where any mythical creatures or "folk" (little people, Huldufolk, etc) associated with bells, or the sound of bells.

Thank-you in advance to anyone who takes the time out of their day to answer my curiosity.

Comment: "Every time a bell rings, an angel gets his wings."

Comment: Giants and trolls were said in Scandinavian folklore to not be able to stand the sound of churchbells. Does that count?

Comment: "A woman drew her long black hair out tight /  And fiddled whisper music on those strings /  And bats with baby faces in the violet light / Whistled, and beat their wings / And crawled head downward down a blackened wall / And upside down in air were towers / Tolling reminiscent bells, that kept the hours / And voices singing out of empty cisterns and exhausted wells."

Comment: In Czech republic, mummified corpses of monks and priests can return to life, to ring the bell and warn against incoming danger. (origin - 30 years war)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somehow associated fairies with bells. Quick check on wiki shows that

> Bells also have an ambiguous role; while they protect against fairies,
>   the fairies riding on horseback — such as the fairy queen — often have
>   bells on their harness

There is a prooflink on the passage: "Briggs (1976) "Bells" p. 20."

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a creature called the Al that is found in old gnostic texts that is described as one of the possible companions for Adam. It wears a hat made of bells that makes it invisible and is known to cause miscarriages and take the livers of living creatures. This all stems from its hatred of being rejected by Adam.

Comment: Can you provide evidence for the Al?

Comment: Also, assuming the word is "AL" not "Ai".  Is this synonymous with "El"?  As Bleh notes, providing some reference to the specific gnostic texts would be helpful, as this would not generally be considered common knowledge.